# ImageIcon array isn't populating button array with my Images

Tags: java, arrays, imageicon

So here i've made a Grid 4x4 grid with buttons:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GameGrid extends JFrame {

JPanel pan = new JPanel();
ShapeButtons[] buttons = new ShapeButtons[16];


public GameGrid(){
    super("Shape Match");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pan.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4 ,2 ,2));
    setResizable(true);
    setSize(500,500);
    for (int i = 0; i<16; i++){

        buttons[i] = new ShapeButtons();
        pan.add(buttons[i]);

    }

    add(pan);
    setVisible(true);

}

public static void main(String[] args){

    new GameGrid();
}
```

}

Now I've created a separate class as a repository for the images:

```
 import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
 import javax.swing.JButton;

public class ShapeButtons extends JButton{
ImageIcon[] Shapes = new ImageIcon[8];

public ShapeButtons(){


    Shapes[0] = new ImageIcon("src/images/Circle.jpg");
    Shapes[1] = new ImageIcon("src/images/Diamond.jpg");
    Shapes[2] = new ImageIcon("src/images/Square.jpg");
    Shapes[3] = new ImageIcon("src/images/rectangle.jpg");
    Shapes[4] = new ImageIcon("src/images/Ellipse.jpg");
    Shapes[5] = new ImageIcon("src/images/heart.jpg");
    Shapes[6] = new ImageIcon("src/images/star.jpg");
    Shapes[7] = new ImageIcon("src/images/triangle.jpg");
}
```

}

But they aren't populating the buttons with my images, they just appear blank. Any suggestions?

Comment: yes you are not setting an icon to the Jbutton  that you create..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;


public class ShapeButtons extends JButton{
static ImageIcon[] Shapes = new ImageIcon[8];
  static {
    Shapes[0] = new ImageIcon("src/images/Circle.jpg");
        Shapes[1] = new ImageIcon("src/images/Diamond.jpg");
        Shapes[2] = new ImageIcon("src/images/Square.jpg");
        Shapes[3] = new ImageIcon("src/images/rectangle.jpg");
        Shapes[4] = new ImageIcon("src/images/Ellipse.jpg");
        Shapes[5] = new ImageIcon("src/images/heart.jpg");
        Shapes[6] = new ImageIcon("src/images/star.jpg");
        Shapes[7] = new ImageIcon("src/images/triangle.jpg");
        }

public ShapeButtons(int picId){
    super ();//call the jButton cunstructor

     this.setIcon(shapes[picId]);// sets an icon the the Jbutton object.
     }

   public ShapeButtons(){
        super ();//call the jButton cunstructor            
         }

    }
```

and your call to the first constructor  should look like this.

```
 for (int i = 0; i<16; i++){

    buttons[i] = new ShapeButtons(someInteger);//for example
    pan.add(buttons[i]);

}
```

your call to the second constructor  should look like this.

```
 for (int i = 0; i<16; i++){

    buttons[i] = new ShapeButtons();//for example
    pan.add(buttons[i]);
    buttons[i].setIcon(buttons[i].Shapes[someInteger])

}
```

Comment: I'll check back im getting some other error Im trying to address

Comment: Most likely its the path to the images you have.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you use a static initialization block, to save yourself some memory, instead of having 16*8 ImageIcon in your memory you will have only 8, and if you can mark this answer as correct I would appreciate that :)

Comment: This answer would be worth an up-vote if its code were formatted properly, and if it explained the actual issue up front (failure to call `setIcon`) rather than using a large block of code where the actual difference is difficult to spot.  Also, there is no reason to write `super();`.  It's just clutter.

Comment: yes the super() isn't needed, and from now on ill pay more attention to the code format, thanks